# select a texture in texture atlas without moving UV

Tags: materials, texture-coordinates

Hello i have this texture atlas
[image]

How do i select one of the texture without using a (cheap and dirty) UV moving? I would preferably plug something in the vector input of the Image texture.

Comment: Hi :). Perhaps the [Mapping node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/mapping.html) is what you're looking for

Comment: @JachymMichal yes I know, but there is some math required for the values, how do I get those?

Comment: Not really, simply adjust the Location XY values to procedurally move the UV map :)